# Problem memory full row locking on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

referring to this question [Concurrency Postgresql UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865130/concurrency-postgresql-update/58280120?noredirect=1#comment102926542_58280120)

I have try with lock row, have another problem with row locking. With alot of transaction (i'm using 3 node of database main, virtual and backup and 6 node of application hit the database) i'm try running 3 hours with row lock, after that the database get memory full and many transaction hit to the database get failed. Do you have any suggestion ?

The actual flow :

I'm using java to working with this, hibernate and PostgreSQL for the database. I have table relation :

> - accounts
> - tenants
> - invoices
> - invoice_items
> - balance

[Database Relation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i43GG.png)

Account activity balance all stored on table invoice_items, for 1 invoices have some items and stored in invoice_items. When account for example account A do topup it will generate data insert to table :

> - invoices
> - invoice_items

the data will be :

> invoices : id, account_id, invoice_date, created_date, created_by

the table invoices

```
                  id                  |               account_id                     |  invoice_date  |       created_date           | created_by
b0a9e664-186b-4b1a-9b43-9edef238765f      e0802b10-70cd-4466-aa53-da1618749809          2019-10-08       2018-10-03 04:10:44.000000      Admin
```

> invoice_items : id, type, invoice_id, amount, account_id, created_date, created_by, current_balance, tenant_record_id

the table invoice_items

```
   id                                |     type     |              invoice_id            |            account_id                  |         created_date        | created_by  | amount | current_balance   |  tenant
b0a9e664-186b-4b1a-9b43-9edef238765f  CBA_ADJ       b0a9e664-186b-4b1a-9b43-9edef238765f    e0802b10-70cd-4466-aa53-da1618749809   2018-10-03 04:10:44.000000      Admin        1000        1000                 1
faef610a-b8bc-4793-8a9e-f9f760e7ee6c  CREDIT_ADJ    b0a9e664-186b-4b1a-9b43-9edef238765f    e0802b10-70cd-4466-aa53-da1618749809   2018-10-03 04:10:44.000000      Admin        -1000       1000                 1
1eaff7c3-226a-42c2-be1c-2939d5b72a60  CBA_ADJ       ab77a359-42ce-4878-bb77-8e66e4227a4d    e0802b10-70cd-4466-aa53-da1618749809   2018-10-03 05:22:43.000000      Admin          1          999                 1
0a73af7f-3310-444c-b852-e5b3931fbbb6    USAGE       ab77a359-42ce-4878-bb77-8e66e4227a4d    e0802b10-70cd-4466-aa53-da1618749809   2018-10-03 05:22:43.000000      Admin         -1          999                 1
7bfc627e-01a3-4a5c-9531-deec9d526c54  CBA_ADJ       a9fe1419-1aa1-4d4b-9af5-a62c4b44ed1c    e0802b10-70cd-4466-aa53-da1618749809   2018-10-03 06:24:43.000000      Admin          1          998                 1
bd3d7241-e18a-443e-a8d0-0dd74af51e27    USAGE       a9fe1419-1aa1-4d4b-9af5-a62c4b44ed1c    e0802b10-70cd-4466-aa53-da1618749809   2018-10-03 06:24:43.000000      Admin         -1          998                 1
```

because i cant handle the current balance via application, i try handle with trigger, when new record was inserted do procedure to insert to table balance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_insert_currentbalance()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

    PERFORM 1 FROM invoice_items
    WHERE type = NEW.type and external_key = new.external_key
    ORDER BY created_date, id DESC LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE OF invoice_items;

  IF new.type = 'CBA_ADJ' THEN
    insert into balance (invoice_id, balance, invoice_items_id)
        values (new.invoice_id, (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM invoice_items WHERE  account_id= new.account_id and type=new.type), new.invoice_id);
  END IF;

return null;
END;

$function$
;
```

For the type when data insert have couple row with type :

> CBA_ADJ and USAGE -> is type for transaction
>
> CBA_ADJ and CREDIT_ADJ is type for toupup

the type apply is credit and debit, to get current balance just calculate with SUM of amount belongs with account_id and tenants from table invoice_items with type "CBA_ADJ". The query :

```
 IF new.type = 'CBA_ADJ' THEN
    insert into balance (invoice_id, balance, invoice_items_id)
        values (new.invoice_id, (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM invoice_items WHERE  account_id= new.account_id and type=new.type), new.invoice_id);
  END IF;
```

Comment: Can you describe that with more detail? Show DDL for all objects involved, the queries and an exact description of what happens.

Comment: i have try described, sorry for the bad english